# Using sed to replace 1 line with a multi-line variable in ksh

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, sed, ksh

I have the following text in a file:

```
XXXX
NNNN
YYYY
NNNN
ZZZZ
NNNN
```

I want to replace the NNNN to make it look like this:

```
XXXX
NNNN
DUTY FORECASTER:
YYYY
NNNN
DUTY FORECASTER:
ZZZZ
NNNN
DUTY FORECASTER:
```

How do I use sed to replace a variable with more than one line? Is there a better way of doing this without using sed?

I have tried the following to no avail, with and without double qoutes:

```
sed 's/NNNN/"$value1"/g' testfile
sed 's/NNNN/'"$value1"'/g' testfile
sed 's/NNNN/${value1}/g' testfile
sed 's/NNNN/'"${value1}"'/g' testfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ value1="DUTY FORECASTER:"
$ echo -e 'abc\ndef\nghi\ndef\n' | sed "s/def/def\n$value1/g"
abc
def
DUTY FORECASTER:
ghi
def
DUTY FORECASTER:
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so very much! Yippie!